# Can redirect website/page when site server is down (This Site Can't Be Reached)?

Tags: html, windows-10, vs-web-site-project

is there any possibility to redirect the website or a page on my site, in case the server crashes (is down) ? I mean, I get sometimes the error "This Site Can't Be Reached", because of my hosting servers, and somehow I want to redirect to another website only when this error appears.

can be done, somehow?

Comment: How would your server communicate, if it's down?

Comment: cloud..or something :)

Answer (score 0):

Not directly. You can't send an instruction to the browser to redirect if it can't make a connection to your site in the first place.

You can put another service, with better uptime, in front of your site (e.g. Amazon CloudFront) and have your visitors request from their services instead of directly from yours. Obviously this doesn't work so well if you have personalised content.

Answer (score 0):

CloudFront or another edge-cache would do this for you. It stores a copy of your website in a cache that sits in-front of your website. When it detects your website is unhealthy (i.e. down), it can display some predefined html that you store in e.g. an S3 bucket. In terms of redirecting to another website, you could put a link in that html, but it wouldn't be an automatic 'failover' where if your site is down, another entire web page loads.